# Bayesian Optimization

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, bayesian

Does any one have an idea as to why the following code not produce the same global maxima value on multiple runs?

```
import sys
from numpy import sin
sys.path.append("./")
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

bo = BayesianOptimization(lambda x, y: ((((sin(((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/((((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))+0.8*((sin(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))),
                         {"x": (-20,20), "y": (-20, 20)})



#bo.explore({'x': [7,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9,8], 'y': [-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]})
gp_params = {"alpha": 1e-5, "n_restarts_optimizer": 2}

bo.maximize(init_points=5, n_iter=25, acq="ucb", kappa=10, **gp_params)

# The output values can be accessed with self.res
print(bo.res['max'])
```

I have tried playing the values in the .maximize function but achieved no success. Is there anyway by which I can make this return the same correct value on multiple runs?

Comment: Not a convex function maybe?

Comment: It is a convex function.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the function to maximize is itself unknown. Bayesian optimization is just probing the function at different points and exploring/exploiting the function to find the minima. Since you set `kappa=10`, your algorithm is good at exploring (I think). However, I don't have a good answer for you as to why it cannot find the global maxima. The only problem maybe is it finishes exploring before it finds the maxima.

Comment: So if I increase the number of iterations, it should give it enough time to find the maxima?

Comment: You can try two things. 1. Use the default value of `kappa` (I think `2.576`) and 2. increase the number of iterations. You will do more exploitation and less exploration, which is what you want here given that the function is convex. Increasing the number of iterations will ensure that this exploitation finishes.

Comment: You said that The algorithm is just probing for different values right? My given space for x and y are [-20,20]. So there are almost infinite values for the algorithm to probe. Is there a possibility of reducing this space? Maybe taking values every 0.01? So that the algorithm can converge faster?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169058/discussion-between-potato-and-parag-s-chandakkar).